# Not able to install applications

Tags: software-installation, apt

This error keeps showing up

```
E: mysql-common: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
E: libmysqlclient20: 25.0000:dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your package manager is corrupt somehow. Have a look at this answer.

https://askubuntu.com/a/773443/495472

Also, try googling the error. That's how I found the solution :)